# Remove line breaks from text file

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a function that reads a string from a txt file and passes this back to a variable. On the variable I then have a `case` block. It is not working despite both the `case` condition and the string that variable value contains being identical.

Here's my code (much of it is omitted interest of length of the post, but this is the part not working properly):

```
vFile = LCase(Trim(Replace(readFile(DirFile & match.Value & ".txt"), "\r", "")))
vFile = Replace(vFile, " ", "")
vFile = Replace(vFile, vbLf, "")
Debug.Print ("Value in variable fromFile: " & fromFile)
Select Case vFile
    Case "abc":
        Debug.Print ("ABC!")
    Case "efg":
        Debug.Print ("EFG!")
    Case Else:
        Debug.Print ("Error: " & vFile)
End Select
```

This is printing to my "immediate window" the following:

```
Value in variable vFile: abc 

Error: abc
```

The `case else` block is running despite the content of the variable being "abc" which matches the "abc" block. Why isn't this running correctly?

EDIT:

This is what is being printed (there's also two whitespaces before the `'` on the newline.

```
Value in variable vFile: 'abc 
'
Error: 'abc 
'
```

Comment: Your final print statement will not tell you whether the variable has trailing spaces or other unexpected characters. Generally I write my debugging prints in the style `Debug.Print ("Error: '" & vFile & '"')` to make it clear what is in the variable.

Comment: Aha! It seems a carriage return is in the mix or newline though I thought using `Trim` would have sorted this? I have edited my question to reflect what is being printed.

Comment: Trim only removes spaces and tabs. You can use Replace(readFile(..), "\r", ""), though.

Comment: Still having no luck. Have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: VB(A) does not support character escapes like "\r". To remove line breaks, depending on your needs remove `vbCr`, `vbLf`, or `vbCrLf`.

Comment: instead of using excat match for comparaison, try with `if instr(1,vFile,"abc") then `...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to use the constants: `vbCrLf` in the `Replace` function as opposed to `\n` or `\r`, etc..